# How to iteratively rename a string in a field of a data frame without using a for loop in r?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have a data frame with a field with file names and I want to replace a part of the name with a corresponding value of another field.

```
X                                                                   fileName answer guess1 guess2 confidence1 confidence2
1     5 D:/TrailCam/raw_images_renamed\\\\R1/R1__2021-06-11__12-49-14(1).JPG      1      1      0      0.9948      0.0052
2     1 D:/TrailCam/raw_images_renamed\\\\R2/R2__2021-06-11__12-49-15(2).JPG      1      1      0      0.8326      0.1674
3 22762 D:/TrailCam/raw_images_renamed\\\\S1/S1__2021-06-11__12-49-15(2).JPG      1      1      0      0.8326      0.1674
4     2 D:/TrailCam/raw_images_renamed\\\\S2/S2__2021-06-11__12-49-37(4).JPG      1      1      0      0.9073      0.0927
```

Specifically, I want to replace the R1, R2, etc folder with value in guess1 column.
I wrote a for loop that does the trick but it is very slow as I have ~20000 records. Is there a faster way to do what this for loop does?

```
for (i in classfile3$fileName){ 
    classfile3$fileName = file.path(
        wd_images_raw_renamed,
        classfile3$guess1, 
        basename(as.character(classfile3$fileName))
    )
}
```

Comment: Interestingly you do not even use `i` iterator variable. Remove `for` loop and curly braces and see if you get desired results.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks @Parfait

Answer (score 1):

So this was embarrassingly simple. Thanks to @Parfait the code below works as desired:

```
classfile3$fileName = file.path(
        wd_images_raw_renamed,
        classfile3$guess1, 
        basename(as.character(classfile3$fileName))
    )
```